# Python Cleaner way to get all substrings in a string

Tags: python, string

For example, I have `"Shum"`, I want to get the list `[Shum, Shu, Sh, S]`

This is what I'm doing right now

```
for c in range(len(first_name)):
    if c==0:
        print first_name
    else:
        print first_name[:-c]
```

What's a better, less ghetto way to do this?

Comment: That list isn't all the substrings, as your title asks. Which is it that you want?

Comment: oh, the code prints it out, but if I were to append it to the list it would work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> w="Shum"
>>> [w[:c] for c in range(len(w),0,-1)]
['Shum', 'Shu', 'Sh', 'S']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list-comp

```
>>> [s[:-i] if i!=0 else s for i in range(len(s))]
['Shum', 'Shu', 'Sh', 'S']
```